# VBA vlookup code in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA.
I have 2 sheets under my excel: "Data", "Sheet1".Data sheet is amended every day.
I would like to use vlookup VBA macro to rows added to column A in Sheet1. However my code doesn't give me any results (it works if I run macro under same sheet where data are). Thank you

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Range("B3:D500").Clear
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A3:A50")
Table2 = Data.Range("A3:H24")
Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("B3").Row
Dept_Clm1 = Sheet1.Range("B3").Column
Dept_Clm2 = Sheet1.Range("C3").Column
Dept_Clm3 = Sheet1.Range("D3").Column
For Each cl In Table1
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 6, False)
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 7, False)
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 8, False)    
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to code the solution it would be better if you dimension the worksheets as such:

```
Dim sWS as worksheet   'Source worksheet
dim tWS as worksheet   'Target worksheet
dim aCell as range

with thisworkbook
  set sws = .sheets("Data")
  set tws = .sheets("Sheet1")
end with

for each acell in sws.range("A3:A50")
  with tws
     .cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm1).value = application....
     'also check out the offset function for fetching values in cells to the left or right of the cell you are looping down through.
  end with
next acell
```

Alternatively, check out the Match, Index and Indirect formulas on how to transfer data from one worksheet to another. The three functions are more efficient and accurate than vLookup, especially if you are transferring three cells from one worksheet to another.

Comment: Great- thank you very much. On top Ihave replaced vlookup by index&match and it is faster

Comment: Please remember to vote/approve the answer for the benefit of future readers.